# WSO2 - How to Pass URL parameter from WSO2 API manager to WSO2 ESB

Tags: api, curl, wso2-esb

I have created a API in API manager.
I can invoke it with

```
curl -X GET --header "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" http://localhost:8281/generatereports/1.0/Reports?reportid=201
```

I want to pass this reportid in the Proxy.
I have written a custom in sequence  getrepotidseq.xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="getrepotidseq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property expression="$url:reportid" name="uri.var.reportid" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log>
        <property expression="get-property('uri.var.reportid')" name="Reportid"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

I am assigning this sequence(while creating the API in API Manager) in the "InFlow" - Message Mediation Policies by checking the "enable message mediation" check box.

The Proxy code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="generateReportsSvc" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log>
                <property name="MESSAGE:" value="*********************Inside GenerateReport Proxy*************************"/>
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.reportid')" name="uri.var.reportid======"/>
            </log>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

After executing the CURL command. In API logs i am getting below message:

```
Reportid = 201
```

But in Integrator log :

```
uri.var.reportid====== = null
```

How can i access the parameter reportid in Proxy?

Thank you!